# How to get list items in response from ajax.request jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am working on Asp.net MVC application which has function with a jQuery ajax call as below.
I am getting a response as expected in data/result object.

It has multiple items in array.

How can check these items in if conditions.
In my case i want check item at 0 index where RuleName = "License Denial"

**I do not want to use for each loop, only wants to check first item in an array.**

[image]

Comment: Did you try `JSON.parse(data)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the "data" object is already an array. So, you can modify a condition in the following manner:

```
//if(data["items"][0]["RuleName"] == "License Denial") { ... }
if(data[0].RuleName === "License Denial") { ... }
```